# TFS Merging keeps merging some files without any changes

Tags: tfs, merge

For some unknown reason, TFS seems to keep queuing certain files for merges, even though there are no changes. In the Pending Changes windows, the **Change** column only states **Merge**, and not the usual **Merge, edit** or **Merge, branch**.

Nobody touches these files and yet they keep reappearing under the pending changes merge queue.

I've seen this happen before with a folder that was deleted, but kept reappearing in the merges between branches. In that case, I used **tf destroy** in all branches for that folder's path and it solved the problem. However, in this environment, it's with files that the team wants to keep.

Has anyone else experienced and/or resolved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Try TFS 2010 [SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182621) and [CU1](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26211). It fixed some merge bugs. Like the following:

> Merge or discard in both directions cause unnecessary "empty" merges
>   in future merge attempts.

Comment: uh, this looks very interesting and seems to hint in the right direction. We are seeing "empty merges" on a daily basis. I will backup/update our TFS to see if it works out.

Comment: @Simon did this work you for you? I have not been able to get out TFS server down to apply these updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed you can use `tfpt uu` to undo changes to any unchanged files (yes, it's well annoying when files are flagged as changed and you get told they are identical!).

Comment: This doesn't work on merges.  You can however undo the pending changes, then select "No to all" when it asks you if you want to undo files that actually changed.

Comment: The "No to all" will be applyed only to modified files. Newly added files will not be merged. As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619885/files-listed-as-pending-changes-when-doing-merges-that-didnt-change