# TFS baseless merge contains unchanged files in changset

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, baseless-merge

I am doing a baseless merge between a branch B and C, since we do not want to go to trunk and down. B and C are latest with all trunk changes.

Before I did a baseless merge in Visual Studio 2013, I did compare of the two branches, It said **6220 files compared(150 different, 179 only in source and 213 only in target)**, so I was happy.

Even after i did the merge it came up with around 100+ conflicts to resolve, But what worried me was that the changeset had 6000+ files, so it is clear that if i check-in TFS would check-in files which have not been changed as well.

Is there an option so that the **final merged changeset contains only the files that are different + only in source +only in target** ?

***Here is what I did to do the merge and avoid unchanged files in the changeset***

1. Exclude all the newly added files that is only in source (fortunately I had this entire list)
2. Undo your pending changes. When you get the confirmation dialog choose "No to all". Visual Studio will take some time to process and will end up with the files that have only changed.
3. Then Include the newly added files that was excluded in Step 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a normal phenomenon. When you did the baseless merge, every single file in the solution was marked as changed and listed in the pending changes during check in. There is no option which you can simply do a merge to achieve your requirement.

However, you can try below workaround `undo your pending changes. When you get the confirmation dialog choose "No to all". Only your pending changes should be left.`from this question [Files listed as pending changes when doing merges that didn't change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619885/files-listed-as-pending-changes-when-doing-merges-that-didnt-change/15643286#15643286)
Note: This works when you only have changes to files. It will not merge any New files that you have added.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly fine. But yes, i had to unselect the new files before doing it.