# Unchanged .config files included in check in after Tfs merge?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

My team develops a web application, using Visual studios 2013 with Tfs source control. We develop in two seperated teams.

We have 3 branches, one for the UI team development, one for the Server side and one for integration.

In the end of each iteration we merge from UI branch and from Server branch to Integration, and after the integration we merge back from integration to the other branches.

In many cases we are having difficulties with those merges, because of files that are added to the merge, without them being changed. We don't know what to do with those files - such as Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config.

Is there a particular reason for those files to be added to the merge without having any difference? Should we check them in? Can we do something to prevent those filed being added to check ins?

Edit:
The merge was not baseless, it happens to us almost every time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a normal phenomenon. Since there’s no branch relationship between them. You are doing the **baseless merge**, every single file in the solution was marked as changed and listed in the pending changes during check in. Generally speaking, you had to check in these unchanged files.

However, if you don't want to check in them. You can try below workaround `undo your pending changes. When you get the confirmation dialog choose "No to all". Only your pending changes should be left.` from this question [Files listed as pending changes when doing merges that didn't change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619885/files-listed-as-pending-changes-when-doing-merges-that-didnt-change/15643286#15643286)

Note: This works when you only have changes to files. It will not merge any New files that you have added.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this was not a baseless merge. Is there a work around for a merge like this when a lot of files has been added?

Comment: If you merge between branches with a branch-relation (parent child for example) , it is "normal" merging. If you merge between two branches without a relation (for example different branch structure or you deleted the parent...) it is a baseless merge. According to your description, there are not parent child relationship with UI branch and  Server branch  at least.

Comment: If the all merges are normal merge, then the unchanged .config files will not include in the pending changes. Details about baseless merge you can check this link from MSDN： https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx

Comment: I have a slightly altered solution which works even when there are new files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41471514/1411039