# Why does TFS show pending changes for all my files when I haven't changed anything?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

I am new to using TFS source control.

I have a large project which I have been porting from SVN. I am checked in and up to date with all projects. However, I opened up Visual Studio today and all project items are in the pending changes included window even though there are no changes.

I haven't touched or edited any of the files for my TFS files since last time.

To verify, I used Araxis Merge to do a folder comparison and can see that no actual changes have taken place.

Why are these unchanged files appearing in my check-in window?

Here is an example of a diff in visual studio from the previous version:
[image]
 I can't see anything!

Hopefully this shows my local workspace

[image]

Comment: Line endings is certainly a possibility.

Comment: Don't you have the option to view a Diff within VS for any of those files to view what VS thinks has changed???

Comment: Araxis Merge has settings that specify to ignore white-space. Using Araxis Merge doesn't necessarily mean that there were not any changes...

Comment: Are you using server workspace or local workspace?

Comment: Is that what you mean by local workspace?

Comment: Yes, that post helped. I don't see an option to mark as answer so I will if that becomes available.

Comment: @jwize, If the solution of Lu is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create or edit a workspace, you can specify whether its location is **Local** or **Server**.  Local Workspaces are TFS's attempt at DVCS and actually gives you a much more SVN-Like experience.

Edit the workspace and choose **advanced**, you could see the **Location** of workspace type.

[image]

Maybe formatting, line endings, encoding. Do a diff using Beyond Compare or something to see what changed.

If nothing changed, check if you are using the same workspace. You may select another workspace than you used.

In **Source Control Explorer**, check if you choosed the workspace the workspace you were work in.

[image]

If all above not work, you could also try this workaround, select all the files in **"Pending changes"** window and activate the context menu. Then click "**Undo...**" > **"Undo Changes"** > **"No to All"**. 
The files **without changes** will be rolled back.  More details please take a look at this question: [how to undo pending changes of files that are unchanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657465/how-to-undo-pending-changes-of-files-that-are-unchanged/46666585#46666585)