# TFS was offline, going online shows way to many files were changed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

TFS 2018 was offline only for a day and I only made a couple of changes to a 7 project solution (most of the various projects are base projects like models, repositories, interfaces, etc.) 
I had to overwrite files to continue because apparently they were read only.  Anyway, I'm going back online today and I'm afraid to checkin my local changes because it shows I've changed nearly 80 files which is impossible, I only changed like 2 or 3 files.

Should I check them in anyway?  I'm afraid I'll mess up something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, seems you are using server workspace (files are ready only).

> **Work offline with difficulty and with poor performance**
>
> When you are offline in a server workspace, you cannot work with your
>   local files because they are read-only until you check them out. You
>   can check out files only from Solution Explorer, and only after you
>   switch to offline mode (as explained below). While you're offline, you
>   can't perform any other operations, such as add, delete, rename, or
>   undo.
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops)*

To edit a workspace, you can specify whether its location is **Local** or **Server**.  Local Workspaces which could work offline easily. You can quickly begin editing a file when your network connection is unavailable or unreliable. From Solution Explorer you can add, edit, delete, rename, undo, and compare items in your workspace even when you're not connected to your Team Foundation Server.

Edit the workspace and choose **advanced**, you could see the **Location** of workspace type.

[image]

---

In your scenario, you could do a diff using Beyond Compare or something to see what changed.

If nothing changed, **check if you are using the same workspace**. You may select another workspace than you used.

In **Source Control Explorer**, check if you choosed the workspace the workspace you were work in.

[image]

If all above not work, you could also try this workaround, select all the files in **"Pending changes"** window and activate the context menu. Then click "**Undo...**" > **"Undo Changes"** > **"No to All"**. 
The files **without changes** will be rolled back.  More details please take a look at this question: [how to undo pending changes of files that are unchanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657465/how-to-undo-pending-changes-of-files-that-are-unchanged/46666585#46666585)

Comment: No idea, I just checked them in.  We'll see over time if it messed anything up.

Comment: Update: After checking them all in I can say we never saw any issues.