# Why I see the merges I did the other way?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge, branch

Let' say I have a simple architecture in TFS as follow:
-Production
-Integration
-Dev_Branch

-I do a merge from Production to Integration.
Ok.

A day later, I need to do a merge from Dev_Branch to Production:
-First I merge from Dev_Branch to Integration
Ok.
-Then I merge from Integration to production

And here, in the list of merge-able changes, I see the merge made yesterday (from Production to Integration)!

And it seems that even if I select this changeset, it doesn't apply any changes at all.

Why my changes list is polluted with merges did the other way?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but for the moment the problem did not occurs again.

Comment: Glad to here the issue is go on, if you got any other tfs related issue, feel free to create new case here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems some unchanged files also listed in pending changes. As a workaround you could undo the annoying changes, only keep the "Real" changes, detail steps please follow below:

Select all pending files
on context menu click 'Undo...' ,before getting to the confirmation dialog, you are presented with a window to select which files to undo. This window has sortable columns. You can sort by the `Change` column and select only the files with `merge` status (these are the unchanged files; `merge, edit` are edited files and `merge, branch` are new files). Just click Undo Changes with just those selected, and then enjoy the beauty of an uncluttered merge changeset.

[image: Example]

For more detail you could also take a look at *broken-e's* answer in this question: [Files listed as pending changes when doing merges that didn't change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619885/files-listed-as-pending-changes-when-doing-merges-that-didnt-change/15643286#15643286)

Comment: Ok so your guess is that there are non modified files. I will be focus on that from now, thanks.

Comment: @Papadoc I created a  three level structure branch, could not reproduce your issue at my environment. Not sure if they are just non modified files in your side, you could double check this, if they are, then you should use the above workaround.