# TFS 2017 branch merge issue - throws message "Some files in pending changes"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, branching-and-merging

I am trying to merge from developer branch to main its shows some files in pending changes,
Following are the steps I followed 
1.  Merge from Main branch to Dev branch, so the Dev branch have update code
2.  Merger from Dev to Main, however it says some files in pending changes and no new changes in compare tool for those pending changes files.
[Image shows there are still pending changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm9vf.png)

Please let I know, what is missing in this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems some unchanged files also listed in pending changes. As a workaround you could undo the annoying changes, only keep the "Real" changes, detail steps please follow below:

Select all pending files
on context menu click 'Undo...' ,before getting to the confirmation dialog, you are presented with a window to select which files to undo. This window has sortable columns. You can sort by the `Change` column and select only the files with `merge` status (these are the unchanged files; `merge, edit` are edited files and `merge, branch` are new files). Just click Undo Changes with just those selected, and then enjoy the beauty of an uncluttered merge changeset.

[image: Example]

For more detail you could also take a look at *broken-e's* answer in this question: [Files listed as pending changes when doing merges that didn't change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619885/files-listed-as-pending-changes-when-doing-merges-that-didnt-change/15643286#15643286)